# Кнопка HTML & PHP

Tags: php, html

Мне нужно создать форму в которой будет кнопка типа Submit и два текстовых поля, в которые можно будет ввести 2 числа, и по нажатию кнопки должен запуститься php-скрипт который к примеру будет выводить надпись " Hello ".
Сделал только форму и кнопку, понятия не имею как вызывать PHP скрипт.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Qwr</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php">   
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first num">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter second num">
        <button type="submit" >Send information</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Файл создан index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускной файл `index.php`

```
<?php
echo (int)$_POST['first']."<br>";
echo (int)$_POST['second'];
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Qwr</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
 // или action='', или вообще без action 
            <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Enter first num">
            <input type="text" name="second" placeholder="Enter second num">
            <button type="submit" >Send information</button>

        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Или с внешним файлом, запускной файл любой, с расширением `php` или `html|htm`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Qwr</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="action.php">   
            <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Enter first num">
            <input type="text" name="second" placeholder="Enter second num">
            <button type="submit" >Send information</button>

        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Файл `action.php`, должен быть в папке с запускным файлом (`index.php`), или в другом месте - тогда нужно правильно указать путь к нему в запускном фале.

```
<?php
    echo (int)$_POST['first']."<br>";
    echo (int)$_POST['second'];
    ?>
```

Дополнительно:

PHP сценарии обработки HTML форм http://coderhs.com/archive/php_send_form

Answer (score 0):

В `<form action="#">` скрипт на этой же странице или ссылку на файл со с скриптом вместо #. Если хочешь использовать значения с полей форм то они попадают в массив $_POST[] или $_GET[] в зависимости от того что ты указал в method.